# Matlab: accessing files in subfolders

Tags: matlab, directory, subdirectory

when I am trying to access files in sub folders of a main folder, How do I come back to main folder.

Ex: C:\Users\User1\Documents\MATLAB\folder1\folder2\folder3

How do I come back to folder2 to access another sub folder in folder2

Answer (score 0):

You either save your current directory in a variable and `cd` there later, or you go up in the directory hierarchy by doing `cd ..`

Comment: I didn't know you can `cd` MATLAB like it's a UNIX terminal. Neat!

Comment: @Adriaan - A lot of the UNIX commands work natively in MATLAB without having to use the bang (`!`) operator or the `system` function :)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the previous answer, could use the ..\ operator.

For eg, in order to read an image in folder4 (which is a sub directory of folder2), you can use this:

```
ex_img = imread('..\folder4\ex_img.jpg');
```